# How to add text below an image in a button in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a button with both an image and text, but since my button is square it's only been displaying the text (as the text is to the right of the button, hence cut off). How do I make it so that the text is below my image in the button so both are visible?

My code is currently like so

```
Button(
                onClick = { navigateToSearch("wtf") },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(178.dp)
                    .height(230.dp)
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.favourites),
                    contentDescription = "null"
                )
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                    text = "Favourites"

                )
            }
```

[image: currently looks like this]

It currently looks like the image above, but I'd like so that the text is formatted below the image rather than squished onto the side. I've tried using:

`modifier = Modifier.paddingFromBaseline(top = 24.dp, bottom = 8.dp)`

But still doesn't work, text still isn't showing up below the image

Comment: Probably have your `Button()` wrap a `Column()` that has your `Image()` and `Text()`.

Answer (score 0):

The container of the content inside a button is a `Row`, that explains why the text appeared on the right of the image.
To show the text below the image add a `Column` as following:

```
Button(
    onClick = { },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(178.dp)
        .height(230.dp)
) {
    Column {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.favourites),
            contentDescription = "null"
        )
        Text(text = "Favourites")
    }
}
```